# How to use Google AutoML Vision Python API to update_dataset

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

Everyone I have a question regarding about Google AutoML Vision Python API. I want to use one of his functions calls `update_dataset`. One of the parameters that I need to enter is `update_mask`. But the official API reference doesn't have a sample code about it, it is required to enter `Field google.protobuf.FieldMask.paths`. So can someone tell me what it is and how to use it? Here is the link to the API reference. Thanks for everyone that can help.

`update_dataset`:
https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.AutoMlClient.update_dataset

`field_mask`: https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.types.FieldMask

Answer (score 0):

In [1] and [2] you have information about Field Masks in update operations. Briefly, field masks are a set of symbolic paths that specify which fields should be updated. If you are updating the whole dataset just initialize the field mask empty as in [3].

You can also take a look at python-docs-samples on github [4], there is no specific example about using the update_dataset function but there are many others. I think that to update the dataset you can just create another one and delete the previous one if it's not a must of the use case.

[1] https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf?_ga=2.160013118.2033425889.1584347340-1628125311.1584193707#fieldmask

[2] https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf?_ga=2.160013118.2033425889.1584347340-1628125311.1584193707#field-masks-in-update-operations

[3] https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/_modules/google/cloud/automl_v1/gapic/auto_ml_client.html#AutoMlClient.update_dataset

[4] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/automl/cloud-client

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs for UpdateDatasetRequest](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/2.0.0/automl_v1/types.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.types.UpdateDatasetRequest.update_mask) the "update mask applies to the [dataset] resource.", so any paths should be relative to the `dataset` object.

For example, if you wanted to update the [`display_name`](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/2.0.0/automl_v1/types.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.types.Dataset.display_name) and [`description`](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/2.0.0/automl_v1/types.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.types.Dataset.description), construct the following field mask:

```
from google.protobuf import field_mask_pb2

update_mask = field_mask_pb2.FieldMask(paths=[
    "display_name",
    "description",
])
```